# Quick Sort Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, sorting

Can anybody please help me out with this sorting question? I am new to the topic of sorting algorithm and just trying to complete the same.

Ques: Sort the below using Quick sorting algorithm

15, 10, 13, 9, 12, 7.

I started solving this and tried a lot.

Selected the last element as Pivot and continuously checked for the comparison with the pivot.

In Step 4 when (i) which points to first element and (j) which also points to first element of the array which is 15 gets swapped with the pivot value 7.

After this i just got confused that how to proceed further.

Partially Solved Answer:
    Let (i) point to 15 which is the first element and (j) point to the last element and Pivot point to 7 as the last element.

```
Step1: 15, 10, 13, 9, 12, 7

Condition Check: 

i<Pivot and j>Pivot
15 < 7 and 12 > 7
false and true 

So (i) will remain pointing to 15 which is at 0th position and (j) will move towards let and will point to 9.

15=>(i), 10, 13, 9=>(j), 12, 7=>PIVOT 

Step 2:
```

Condition Check:
15 < 7 and 9 > 7 
false and true

(i) will remain pointing to 15 which is at 0th position and (j) will will towards left and will point to 13.

```
15=>(i), 10, 13=>(j), 9, 12, 7=>PIVOT
```

Step 3:

Condition Check:
(i) < Pivot and j > Pivot
15 < 7  and 13 > 7
false and true

(i) will remain pointing to 15 which is at 0th position and (j) will move towards left and will point to 10.

```
15=>(i), 10=>(j), 13, 9, 12, 7=>PIVOT
```

Step 4:

Condition Check:
i < Pivot and j > Pivot
15 < 7  and 10 > 7
false and true

(i) will remain pointing to 15 which is at 0th position and (j) will move towards left and will point to 15.

Now (i) and (j) point to the same element so will be swapped 0th element 15 will 7(pivot and last element)

7, 10, 13, 9, 12, 15.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We have no idea what "step 4" means. There is no official numbered steps in quicksort -- or even any standard for what `i` and `j` in a description of quicksort stand for. Each person who writes down a description make those up for himself, and we have no way of knowing whose description you're referring to.

Comment: (Also, I'm not quite convinced that the minutiae of particular sorting algorithms are actually mathematics).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry. I am explaining every single step here. So that you can help me out.

Comment: You might want to look on youtube for tutorials. There are good ones and we probably can't give any better explanation here. Of course I can sort your array, but I guess you want to learn how quicksort works and not a sorted array.

Comment: @N.Beck I have seen the same. But now i am looking for the specified to validate my steps. Can you please help me once with the all steps for sorting?

Comment: This is more a computer science question than a mathematics question.  You would do better to pose it on the computer science stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

- $15,10,13,9,12,7$

Select last element as pivot and then make two sets separated by the pivot

$\varnothing, 7,\{15,10,13,9,12\}$

The first set of elements lower than $7$ is empty, so it is sorted already.
Now you continue with the set on the right.

- $15,10,13,9,12$

Select last element as pivot and then make two sets separated by the pivot

$\{10,9\},12,\{15,13\}$

You have now two sets to sort :

- $10,9$

Select last element as pivot and then make two sets separated by the pivot

$\varnothing,9,\{10\}$

everything sorted

- $15,13$

Select last element as pivot and then make two sets separated by the pivot

$\varnothing,13,\{15\}$

everything sorted

Putting the whole algorithm together we get :

$\begin{cases}
\{15,10,13,9,12,7\}\\
\{\varnothing, 7,\{15,10,13,9,12\}\}\\
\{\varnothing, 7,\{\{10,9\},12,\{15,13\}\}\}\\
\{\varnothing, 7,\{\{\varnothing,9,\{10\}\},12,\{\varnothing,13,\{15\}\}\}\}\\
\{7,9,10,12,13,15\}
\end{cases}$

Of course with an algorithm that works on an array, you have to manipulate the indices so that braces and $\varnothing$ are hidden.

$\begin{cases}
[15,10,13,9,12,7]\\
[7,15,10,13,9,12]\\
[7,10,9,12,15,13]\\
[7,9,10,12,13,15]\\
\end{cases}$